# how to solve a third degree equation of complex roots and coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations

It's not a homework it came in one of our exams and I didn't find anything on the internet that is a high-school level. please give me any hint or answer to solve this in a noncomplicated way.
solve the equation:
$$z^3+(2-i)z^2+(5-2i)z-5i=0.$$
Where the unknown z belongs to the set of complex numbers.

Comment: I think that the standard way to solve a cubic works with complex coefficients too.
Have a look at Mathematical Omnibus, http://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/Books/taba.pdf - there is a (non-standard) way to retrieve the result.

Comment: There are formulas for it, but suppose we don't want to use them. Guess a root. I would try $z=i$. Then divide the polynomial by $z-i$, or $z-$the root you found. You get a polynomial of degree two, which you probably know how to solve.

Comment: Guess?? really!

Comment: If you don't want to guess there are formulas to solve it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function But guessing that $z=i$ is a solution is not very hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$z^3+(2-i)z^2+(5-2i)z-5i=0$$

You can read the relevant section in Wikipedia on [roots of a cubic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) to proceed programmatically, or you can scan the equation to test for roots with some informed "guesses", which in this case, yields one root to be $z_1 = i$.

Then, just as, given a root $z_1 = c$,  divide by the factor $(z - c)$, so using the root $z_1 = i$, divide your cubic by the factor $(z-i)$.

Now you're down to a degree two equation, and finding the other two roots should proceed smoothly for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see what's going on here is to rewrite the equation with all the $i$'s on one side:

$$z^3+2z^2+5z=i(z^2+2z+5)$$

Factoring the left hand side as $z(z^2+2z+5)$, it's clear you can move things back to get

$$(z-i)(z^2+2z+5)=0$$

By happenstance (or design), the other two roots, $-1+2i$ and $-1-2i$, are also Gaussian integers.

Comment: Really helpful thanks all.